# Can all command line utlities be scheduled?

Tags: command-line, windows-task-scheduler, hyperion

I am using Hyperion Planning. There are a lot of in-built command line utilities. may I know if all these command line utilities can be scheduled to run using the windows task scheduler?

Comment: This question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

You can run all command using batch file.  Just call batch file from task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux we schedule things as follows:

```
[apphyp@ichypp0013 ~]$ crontab -l
### Minutes hours DayOfMonth Month Weekday(0-6 Sunday-Saturday)
###
###
### DAILY ONLINE BACKUP Plan0
00 20  * * 1-5 /app/ncia/scripts/stop.hyp.sh 2>&1
30 20  * * 1-5 /app/ncia/scripts/backup_Planning0.sh 2>&1
00 22  * * 1-5 /app/ncia/scripts/start.hyp.sh 2>&1
### Automatic Transfer
00 09  * * 1-5 /app/ncia/scripts/automatic.transfer.FMC_to_R2C.sh >> /app/ncia/log/automatic.transfer.FMC_to_R2C.log
00 23  * * 0-4 /app/ncia/scripts/automatic.transfer.HRC_to_HR2C.sh >> /app/ncia/log/automatic.transfer.HRC_to_HR2C.log
30 22  * * 0-4 /app/ncia/scripts/automatic.launch.business.rule.FMC_Admin_PrepareAllData_to_R2C.sh >> /app/ncia/log/automatic.launch.business.rule.FMC_Admin_PrepareAllData_to_R2C.log
```